# What star system/Galaxy did LIGO observe the gravity wave?

Tags: gravity, black-hole, gravitational-waves

Are there any coordinates for the Black Hole system, or galaxy for which the LIGO observations, observed the gravity wave? Any coordinates of the black hole system for which the gravity wave signal has been observed?

Answer (score 5):

The location of GW150914 was rather poorly constrained by the 6.9 ms time difference between the event when it was observed by the two separated LIGO detectors at Livingston and Hanford.

Further details are here 
https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/image/ligo20160211b and this site provides a visualisation of where the waves came from.

[image: Location of GW150914]

The location OF GW150914 can only be constrained to be somewhere within 600 square degrees with 90% confidence. There are millions of possible host galaxies within this region.

Comment: If the Fermi GRB detection that was seen 0.4s after the LIGO detection did originate from the same black hole merger then they claim to be able to shrink the error box to 199 square degrees, but that's still a huge patch of sky!